# Union of uncountable cardinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove the following:

Let $\omega_1$ be the least uncountable cardinal and, for each $n \in \omega$ (here, $\omega$ is the set of natural numbers denoted as an ordinal/cardinal), $n\ge1$, let $\omega_{n+1}$ be the least cardinal that is greater than $\omega_n$. Show that $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\omega_n$ is a cardinal.

I suppose the proof has something to do with transfinite induction/recursion, but I don't know exactly how I'm supposed to use it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $\alpha=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\omega_n$. If you already know that a union of ordinals is an ordinal, then all that remains is to prove that $\alpha$ is a minimal ordinal, i.e., that there is no bijection between $\alpha$ and a smaller ordinal. Suppose that $\beta<\alpha$, and $f:\alpha\to\beta$ is a bijection. Use the fact that

$$\alpha=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\omega_n$$

and the definition of the cardinals $\omega_n$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: Could you give me more hints on how to get to that contradiction?

Comment: @Victor: There must be an $n\in\omega$ such that $\beta\ldots$?

Comment: There must be an n∈ω such that β∈ωn (because β∈α). So... ? I'd already thought of this, but couldn't go any further, and I've been thinking over it for more than 1 hour now... =(

Comment: @Victor: That is the key observation. Now look at $f\upharpoonright\omega_{n+1}$, the restriction of $f$ to $\omega_{n+1}$; it’s a bijection from $\omega_{n+1}$ into $\beta$ and hence into $\omega_n$. Is that possible?

Comment: Ooooh, now I get it! Thanks! =)

Comment: @Victor: You’re welcome!